# Is this a recommended approach to find the square of the sides of a triangle whose been divided by a median?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Figure 1 shows a triangle $\textrm{ABC}$ whose side $\textrm{BC = 4
>  inches}$. It is known that $\textrm{AM}$ is a median whose length is
>   equal to $\textrm{1 inch}$. Find the sum of the squares from the other two sides
>   of triangle $\textrm{ABC}$.

The existing alternatives in my book are:

- 12 inches
- 10 inches
- 14 inches
- 15 inches
- 8  inches

The figure is attached below:

[image: Diagram of the problem]

In my attempt to solve this problem what I used was the median length formula which is shown below:

$$m = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2(a^{2}+b^{2})-c^{2}}$$

By plugin the values given:

$$1 = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)-4^{2}}$$

$$2 = \sqrt{2\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)-4^{2}}$$

$$2^{2}= 2\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)-4^{2}$$

$$4 = 2\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)-4^{2}$$

$$16+4=  2\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)$$

$$10 = a^{2}+b^{2}$$

$$a^{2}+b^{2} = 10$$

This is also described in figure 2 from below which it proves how to relate the length of the median and the opposing sides of the triangle other than the base.

[image: Diagram of the solution]

This is based on the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

It states as this:

> the sum of the squares of the lengths of the four sides of a
>   parallelogram equals the sum of the squares of the lengths of the two
>   diagonals.

so,

$$2b^{2}+2a^{2}=4^{2} + 2^{2}$$

$$2\left ( b^{2} + a^{2} \right) = 2 \left ( 2^{3}+ 2 \right)$$

Dividing by $2$ on both sides:

$$b^{2} + a^{2} = 10$$

Therefore the answer would be $\textrm{10 inches}$ which does appears within the alternatives. But I wonder other than the method I used does it exist another ways to obtain what it is being asked?.

Comment: You should have written $2 = \sqrt{2(a^2 + b^2) - 4^2}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry about that. I was in a rush during the typing of the question therefore I did that mistake but I corrected it in a subsecuent edit. I hope that now is accordingly. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Not much left to add to the answers you provided in the post, except +1 for a nicely asked question.

- For quick verification, and trusting that the problem has indeed a unique answer regardless of $\,A\,$, consider the degenerate case where $\,A\,$ lies on $\,BC\,$ one unit away from $\,B\,$ towards $\,C\,$. Then $\,AB=1, AC=3\,$ and $\,AB^2+AC^2=1+9=10\,$.
- Or, in a complex plane where $\,B,C\,$ are at $\,\pm2\,$ and $\,A\,$ lies on the unit circle:
  $$\require{cancel}
  \begin{align}
  |a+2|^2 + |a-2|^2 &= (a+2)(\bar a+2) + (a-2)(\bar a-2) \\
   &= a \bar a + \cancel{2a} + \bcancel{2 \bar a} + 4+ a \bar a - \cancel{2a} - \bcancel{2 \bar a}+ 4 \\
   &= 2 |a|^2 + 8 \\
   &= 10
  \end{align}
  $$

Answer (score 0):

Apply cosine law to both $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle ACM$.

Note that the cosine term will cancel each other because $\cos \theta = - \cos (\pi - \theta)$.